# AWS vs Azure for PHP. Factors determining on which "cloud" to deploy

Tags: php, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

Is there a list of pros-cons for deploying a PHP application on the cloud for AWS or Azure?

Which factors would make AWS a better choice over Azure and Vice-versa?

If anyone has chosen to use, either one instead of the other for a number or reasons I would really want to know why.

Comment: Good question. I can't really answer it, but from quick look the PHP SDK for Azure looks promising http://phpazure.codeplex.com/, in some ways more so than the AWS offering (http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=131). Then again, AWS is a much more established IaaS provider and *right now* probably a safer choice...

Comment: I have been monitoring the windows Azure platform and i agree that is promising. Also attended an MS event for Azure and i must say i was impressed. The 'safe' factor that you mention, was not on my list but it is now. I guess i will never know until i try both :)

Comment: AWS requires less changes to the code to get up and running but if you're writing from scratch that's less of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has released the AWS SDK for PHP. http://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php

Answer (score 2):

This basically boils down to a windows vs linux discussion. For a PHP server environment, I'd normally advise a LAMP server setup (linux/apache/mysql/php) and azure is (as far as I know and expect from microsoft) windows-only. Unless you really *need* windows for some reason, a linux server performs better and is more stable than a windows server, at least for a php/apache setup, and is cheaper.

I have some AWS servers running CentOS at AWS for more than a year now, and never experienced problems.

Comment: It does not boil down to windows vs linux since AWS supports both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific application you are talking about? I think choice will probably depend on the type of application and the cloud services required by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Answering not as much from technical, but on commercial considerations- you can get MS Azure for free for upto 2 yrs, if you are subscribed to some of their programs... that could be a deciding factor (was for me!!)